# PDF to Excel (xlsx) conversion

Tags: pdf, document-converter, microsoft-excel

I am in need of software (Not online service) that can convert my PDF documents to Excel accurately.

I have tried Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and Nitro, they are great at the conversion, but I cannot justify the heavy cost of these products, just for the one feature of PDF to Excel conversion.

Adobe "Export to PDF" service is cheap and if it works the same way as their software then the conversion will be good, but I am buying for business and require multiple licences, this is not an option for the "Export to PDF" service.

I have tried a coupe of free versions (Free PDF to Excel Converter, Bravo Free PDF to Excel, more that I cannot remember the name of)  but the output is very poor, and that is being generous.

Ideally freeware but I am willing to pay if required, but only for software that converts accurately and not on a monthly subscription basis.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you looked into using Chrome Extension and they have that but it requires you to be login to Chrome ?

Comment: It woudl have been helpful to post a URL for the Chrome extension which you recommend

Comment: Try [GroupDocs](https://products.groupdocs.app/conversion/xlsx-to-pdf), it supports many file format conversions.